# Dynamic Column selection in BI Answers/views based on Dashboard prompt selections

Tags: oracle, obiee, bi-publisher, oracle-bi, oracle-analytics

I need to have a BI Dashboard where the columns(eg, **Brand**)  or group of columns ( eg, **Company, Company site**) have to hide/show in all analysis of dashboard based on check box selections with **Brand and Company** respectively. I am able to pass the column header and formula based on selection through Presentation Variable in Prompts, but stuck with hiding columns when the respective check box in unchecked. Note than I'm using OACv5.8.
Thanks in advance for any help on how to achieve/proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use standard, out-of-the-box functionality like column selectors or show/hide sections?

Instead pf playing with presentation variables and trying to fiddle around.